# How do I combine multiple OpenAPI 3 specification files together?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I want to combine an API specification written using the OpenAPI 3 spec, that is currently divided into multiple files that reference each other using `$ref`. How can I do that?

Comment: take a look at the [openapi-preprocessor](https://github.com/dolmen-go/openapi-preprocessor/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the open-source project [speccy](https://github.com/wework/speccy).

Open the terminal and install `speccy` by running (requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)):

`npm install speccy -g`

Then run:

`speccy resolve path/to/spec.yaml -o spec-output.yaml`

Comment: Speccy is not actively maintained anymore

Comment: 13 dependencies, 13 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 3 high, 3 critical)

Comment: How could we use this with private repo? I've searched through the code, it is using the `node-fetch` and won't accept any parameters for header and auth.

Answer (score 31):

I wrote a quick tool to do this recently. I call it openapi-merge. There is a library and an associated CLI tool:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-merge
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-merge-cli

In order to use the CLI tool you just write a configuration file and then run `npx openapi-merge-cli`. The configuration file is fairly simple and would look something like this:

```
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "inputFile": "./gateway.swagger.json"
    },
    {
      "inputFile": "./jira.swagger.json",
      "pathModification": {
        "stripStart": "/rest",
        "prepend": "/jira"
      }
    },
    {
      "inputFile": "./confluence.swagger.json",
      "disputePrefix": "Confluence",
      "pathModification": {
        "prepend": "/confluence"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "output": "./output.swagger.json"
}
```

For more details, see the [README on the NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-merge-cli).

Comment: Finally someone who combines multiple specifications, not "merges" the `$ref`s! Thank you so much 

Comment: So far, this tool is pretty dope!
`echo '{"inputs":[{"inputFile":"./lib.yaml"},{"inputFile":"./api.yaml"}],"output":"./v1.json"}' > ${PWD}/docs/merge.json`
`docker run --rm -ti -v ${PWD}/docs:/docs -w /docs 3apaxicom/npx openapi-merge-cli --config ./merge.json`

Comment: @Robert Massaioli great tool. but is this not maintained anymore? I can see a lot of open PRs and there are no releases in 2 years.

Comment: this tool cannot handle duplicates - if you have two spec files with the same endpoint in it, it will error. There seems to be no settings for skipping duplicates

Comment: @Bee - https://github.com/iouring-engineering/openapi-merge  we have made a fork of openapi-merge and enhanced

Comment: @Kappacake - https://github.com/iouring-engineering/openapi-merge This repo is actively managed and daily used in our pipelines to generate spec files from various microservices

Comment: This ... mmm... tool failed to merge two simple files (just hangs). And it DOES NOT SUPPORT JSON LINKS! Totally useless. Seriously people stop writing cli on such dump langs like js or python, there is golang in 2023.

Comment: By the way original openapi-merge at least works

Answer (score 25):

Most OpenAPI tools can work with multi-file OpenAPI definitions and resolve `$ref`s dynamically.

If you specifically need to get a single resolved file, [**Swagger Codegen**](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) can do this. Codegen has a **CLI version** (used in the examples below), a **Maven plugin** ([usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71523683/113116)) and a **Docker image**.

The input file (`-i` argument of the CLI) can be a local file or a URL.

Note: Line breaks are added for readability.

#### OpenAPI 3.0 example

Use **Codegen 3.x** to resolve OpenAPI 3.0 files:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.35.jar generate
     -l openapi-yaml
     -i ./path/to/openapi.yaml
     -o ./OUT_DIR
     -DoutputFile=output.yaml
```

`-l openapi-yaml` outputs YAML, `-l openapi` outputs JSON.

`-DoutputFile` is optional, the default file name is `openapi.yaml` / `openapi.json`.

#### OpenAPI 2.0 example

Use **Codegen 2.x** to resolve OpenAPI 2.0 files (`swagger: '2.0'`):

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.28.jar generate
     -l swagger-yaml
     -i ./path/to/openapi.yaml
     -o ./OUT_DIR
     -DoutputFile=output.yaml
```

`-l swagger-yaml` outputs YAML, `-l swagger` outputs JSON.

`-DoutputFile` is optional, the default file name is `swagger.yaml` / `swagger.json`.

Comment: I personally could not figure out an option to "combine" or "merge" multiple input definitions, using codegen; could you provide an example? The `-i` swtich accepts single input - event passing multiple values (`-i def1.json -i def2.json`) does not work

Comment: @asceta this Q&A is about the situation when you have one "main" API definition file that uses `$ref` to reference external definitions. If you mean you have two different API definitions (with different sets of endpoints, schemas, etc.) that you want to merge, it's a different use case, and you should [ask a new question](/questions/ask?tags=openapi).

Comment: I want to merge multiple swagger files to a single file.
All these files have same endpoints, but they are split into multiple files based on their version or child operations.
Can merge these multiple files to a single be done using Codegen ?

Comment: @NigelThomas no, use [`redocly join`](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/join/) or [`openapi-merge-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-merge-cli) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the [Redocly CLI](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/) was a viable option for doing exactly what you need (addressing `$ref`'s used within specifications).

You can configure the CLI using a [configuration file](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/configuration/) (that **must** be located in the root of your project directory as well as be written in YAML format) which allows you to specify certain linting rules among other things.  But to bundle your specifications, simply perform a `bundle` in the directory of where the configuration file is like so:

```
redocly bundle -o <NameOfFileOrDir>
```

After running this command, all of your `$ref`'s will be replaced with the actual code of whatever the `$ref` was for, combining them into one definition.

If you have multiple elements defined in your `apis` object in your configuration file (i.e. multiple API definitions), it will create a directory named whatever you specified for the `-o` option and the folder will contain all of your definitions.

Comment: There is also a helpful Visual Studio Code extension for Redocly: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Redocly.openapi-vs-code

Answer (score 3):

For what it worths redoc manages merge of different openapi files - even in different formats (JSON / YAML).

- https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/bundle/
- https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/join/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python script which does this (follows `$refs` which are filesystem paths and in-lines the contents of those files, recursively):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Expand all file-based $ref's inline to produce a single YAML file.

import sys
import os
import yaml

# Is this a local file-based $ref?
# File-based refs look like paths, e.g. "../models/user.yaml".
# Non file-based refs look like URL fragments, e.g. "#/models/user"
def is_file_ref(ref):
    return (ref.startswith("/") or ref.startswith("./") or ref.startswith("../")) \
        and ref.endswith(".yaml")

# Merge two dictionaries.  Throws on key collision.
def merge_or_die(d1, d2):
    for k, v in d2.items():
        if k in d1:
            raise Exception("Refusing to clobber key '%s' with value '%s'" % (k, v))
        d1[k] = v
    return d1

# Recursively descend through the JSON, expanding any file-based refs inline.
def inline_json(js_in, pwd):
    if type(js_in) is dict:
        js_out = {}
        for k, v in js_in.items():
            if k == "$ref" and is_file_ref(v):
                if v.startswith("/"):
                    yml_fpath = v
                else:
                    yml_fpath = os.path.join(pwd, v)
                yml_in = open(yml_fpath, "r").read()
                v = yaml.safe_load(yml_in)
                pwd = os.path.split(yml_fpath)[0]
                js_out = merge_or_die(js_out, inline_json(v, pwd))
            else:
                js_out[k] = inline_json(v, pwd)
        return js_out
    else:
        return js_in

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s <input_file>\n" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    fpath_in = sys.argv[1]
    if fpath_in.startswith("/"):
        yml_fpath = fpath_in
    else:
        yml_fpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fpath_in)
    yml_in = open(yml_fpath, "r").read()
    js_in = yaml.safe_load(yml_in)
    pwd = os.path.split(yml_fpath)[0]
    js_out = inline_json(js_in, pwd)
    yml_out = yaml.dump(js_out, sort_keys=False)
    print(yml_out)
```

```
./inline-yaml.py root.yaml > combined.yaml
```