# How to merge multiple OpenAPI specifications?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I'm digging here around trying to find a solution, how to merge several OpenApi v3 component definitions in one file.

Let's imagine a situation:

1. You decided to split your OpenApi into multiple files in different folders. (see image below)[image: project structure]
2. Now you need to combine all your components.v1.yaml into a single schema (i named it `blueprint.v1.yaml`). 
   Usually, I use `swagger-cli` to merge all `$ref` dependencies, but now it's not a case, because I can not refer to the whole components/schemas object list
   [image: blueprint.v1.yaml content]
3. And use it to build a single OpenApi file with all fields filled: info, components, paths and so on with a `swagger-cli bundle` tool.

So, the question is - how to reuse already defined component blocks (files called components.v1.yaml) in my `blueprint.v1.yaml` file?

P.S. Every `components.v1.yaml` looks like this:
[image: components.v1.yaml content]

And a, for ex, `location-create-single.v1.yaml` path definition is shown on picture below. Mention, that all `$ref` referes to `components.v1.yaml` files.
[image]

Comment: That is a VERY nice looking IDE file browser!  What IDE and theme is that?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail why you can't use `swagger-cli` to merge an entire tree of files? All of your files link to each other, starting with the topmost `blueprint.v1.yaml` through the `<component>-*.yaml` files (e.g. `location-*.yaml`) down to the every `components.v1.yaml` file. What's the problem to traverse through them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I combine multiple OpenAPI 3 specification files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586137/how-do-i-combine-multiple-openapi-3-specification-files-together)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a "native" OpenAPI solution to your problem. [People are discussing for a while about OpenAPI overlays/extends/merges](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1442). There is currently (2020-04-24) not any consensus about this topic.

Although you could implement your own tool [or use an existing one](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1442#issuecomment-558754882) to preprocess your `blueprint.v1.yaml` and generate a *"merged OAS"*.

Comment: P. Savrov any feedback about this answer ?

Answer (score 2):

[openapi-generator-cli](https://openapi-generator.tech) tool is able to merge specification files into single one using the [openapi-yaml](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/openapi-yaml) generator:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i blueprint.v1.yaml -g openapi-yaml
```

where `-i` option specifies an input OpenAPI document.

Comment: Could you explain which option allows you to merge specification files into a single one? It seems to only reference 1 file, rather than multiple or a directory to merge.

Comment: @fuzzi the command above dereferences all the `$ref`s in the specified yaml. With the [`$ref` keyword](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#reference-object) you can reference other documents in any directory you want. The final spec will include all the referenced content.

Answer (score 0):

[`go-swagger`](https://goswagger.io/) has a [`mixin`](https://goswagger.io/usage/mixin.html) command that merges paths, definitions, etc. from multiple OpenAPI specifications, skipping duplicate definitions as required.

Comment: Seems to be only for Swagger 2.0 (Not OpenAPI v3)