# Is there a way to merge a yaml with external references?

Tags: maven, yaml, openapi, openapi-generator

In my project, in order to keep the api yaml clean I use a lot of external references, for example:

```
ApiResponse:
  allOf:
  - $ref: 'includes/apiresponse.yaml#/GenericResponse'
```

Would it possible to generate, along with the code, also a yaml that replaces the $refs with the actual snippet? I'm currently using the openapi maven plugin, but maybe maven already has some other plugin to accomplish that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [How do I combine multiple OpenAPI 3 specification files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54586137/113116) That Q is about OAS2 but the answers apply to OAS2 as well.