# How to generate self-contained specification of openAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Intellij's SwaggerHub Smartbear plugin has functionality 'Export self-contained specification(YAML)' which will resolve all the remote $ref(s) and generate local
definitions of domain models in the generated output document.

Is there a way to do it programmatically for making it as part of build pipeline? Any java program or scripts can we write for the same?

Comment: Do these Q&As answer your question? [How to merge multiple OpenAPI 3.0 specification files into one in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71519460/113116), [How do I combine multiple OpenAPI 3 specification files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54586137/113116)