# How to solve $ref in swagger yaml files

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have multiple yaml files in different directories. ex. a.yaml

a.yaml has a reference such as

```
aref = ../../alphabet/b/src/resources/b.yaml#/components/ref
```

I want to generate 1 file with yaml written in a nice way to copy it to swagger and see changes and the objects are referenced.

tried swagger-merger didn't work corectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How do I combine multiple OpenAPI 3 specification files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54586137/113116)